# Add multiple lists

Tags: r

I have results of a study stored in lists.

In total I have 1000 lists all of which are the same dimension.

Each list contains 39 elements which are matrices of different dimensions.

I would like to sum these list and then divide them by 1000.

I could not figure out a way to do this.

Example:

```
a<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=6)
b<-matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=10)

list1 <- list(a,b)

a<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=6)
b<-matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=10)

list2 <- list(a,b)

a<-matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=6)
b<-matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=10)

list3 <- list(a,b)
```

I want to add list1 + list2 + list3...list1000

and then divide each element in the final list by 1000.

Comment: The position of each matrix is the same in each list so I want to add each matrix to the same matrix

Comment: Are the lists with your real results also separate variables like `list1`, `list2`, ...? Or are they stored in some other list?

Comment: they are stored in separate Rdata files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Map` and `Reduce` and use `mget` to collect all your lists into one list.

```
a<-matrix(1,nrow=5,ncol=6)
b<-matrix(10,nrow=2,ncol=10)

list1 <- list(a,b)
list2 <- list(a,b)
list3 <- list(a,b)

l <- mget(ls(pattern = '^list\\d+$'))
(fl <- Reduce(function(x, y) Map(`+`, x, y), l))

# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
# [2,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
# [3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
# [4,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
# [5,]    3    3    3    3    3    3
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   30   30   30   30   30   30   30   30   30    30
# [2,]   30   30   30   30   30   30   30   30   30    30

Map(`/`, fl, 1000)

# [[1]]
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
# [1,] 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
# [2,] 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
# [3,] 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
# [4,] 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
# [5,] 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003 0.003
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,] 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03  0.03
# [2,] 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.03  0.03
```

Comment: I’m on a crusade to rid R of [stringly typed code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) so I’d like to mention that R has a specific syntax to denote (otherwise invalid) identifiers, via \``+`\` (i.e. with backticks), and that using strings here, while valid, is a weird hack that *shouldn’t* work if R had a proper type system. That said, good answer.

Comment: it's a habit that carries over from do.call, library, etc. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented some recursive utility functions for that. However they don't check the preconditions (equal length, summability of the elements).

**EDIT:** I have fixed the issues mentioned in the comments. The for-loops are replaced by high-order functions, and the function has a better error-behaviour. The function processes also more complex list-structures e.g. lists containing other lists containing numeric elements. It's more (and more complex) than what the OP asked for, but I thought it's worth to be kept in case someone needs a recursive solution.

```
sum_numeric_lists <- function(...){
  lists <- list(...)

  if (length(unique(sapply(lists, length))) > 1) {
    stop("lists are not of equal length")
  }

  Map(function(...) {
    elems <- list(...)
    if (length(unique(sapply(elems, class))) > 1) {
      stop("corresponding elements have different types")
    }
    if (is.list(elems[[1]])) {
      sum_numeric_lists(...)
    } else if(is.numeric(elems[[1]])){
      Reduce(`+`, elems)
    } else {
      warning("lists contain types other than numeric, which are preserved as NULL elements")
      NULL
    }
  }, ...)

}


devide_numeric_list_by <- function(l, divisor){

  lapply(X = l, FUN = function(elem) {
    if (is.list(elem)) {
      devide_numeric_list_by(elem, divisor)
    } else if(is.numeric(elem)){
      elem / divisor
    } else {
      warning("lists contain types other than numeric, which are preserved as NULL elements")
      NULL
    }
  })

}

avg_numeric_lists <- function(...){
  sum_l <- sum_numeric_lists(...)
  devide_numeric_list_by(sum_l, length(list(...)))
}
```

Some tests:

```
avg_numeric_lists()
avg_numeric_lists(NULL)
avg_numeric_lists(list())
avg_numeric_lists(list(NULL))
avg_numeric_lists(list(1))
avg_numeric_lists(list(list(1)))

list1 <- list(m_first_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 20, replace = T), nrow=4, ncol=5),list(m_sec_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 6, replace = T), nrow=3, ncol=2)),"not_a_list_or_numeric",a_number = 1)
list2 <- list(m_first_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 20, replace = T), nrow=4, ncol=5),list(m_sec_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 6, replace = T), nrow=3, ncol=2)),"not_a_list_or_numeric",a_number = 2)
list3 <- list(m_first_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 20, replace = T), nrow=4, ncol=5),list(m_sec_lvl = matrix(sample(1:10, 6, replace = T), nrow=3, ncol=2)),"not_a_list_or_numeric",a_number = 3)
avg_numeric_lists(list1, list2, list3)
```

For calling it on all lists in the global environment (as suggested by rawr):

```
do.call(what = avg_numeric_lists, args = mget(ls(pattern = '^list\\d+$')))
```

Comment: Did you downvote? I wrote this answer before you specified, that the lists come from 1000 .RData files... But I guess you'll be happy with the other answer then.

Comment: I didn’t downvote this either but it’s not very good code. It’s very hard to read, and the loops should probably be replaced by appropriate higher-order list functions. Furthermore, it could benefit from proper error handling, rather than writing strings into the result (there are very few cases where this is appropriate).